# Technical SAML for API calls in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, saml

Is it possible to generate a technical SAML and propagate it while making a REST API call?

While flink documentation doesn't really talk about SAML anywhere, is it possible to rely upon external Scala/Java dependencies for achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can put an authenticating proxy in front of the Flink REST API and manage it however you want.